# Industry benchmarks to assess data mining tools

Tags: comparison, benchmarking, data-mining

I'm looking for data mining tools for a project and in line with that I have put up another post in SO. I'm currently looking at different tools and am wondering whether any industry benchmark exists to asses different data mining tools so that I can refer it do a better evaluation of tools.

Please let me know if any such benchmark exists or it just boils down to picking the tool which suits your needs ...

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For evaluations of data mining tools on features/etc, how about these links:

- [A Comparison of Leading Data Mining Tools](http://datamininglab.com/pubs/kdd98_elder_abbott_nopics.pdf) (1998) - dated but pretty informative
- [Magic Quadrant for Customer Data-Mining Applications](http://mediaproducts.gartner.com/reprints/sas/vol5/article3/article3.html) (2008) - a bit non-technical

Answer (score 0):

Here are some standard sets of test data to benchmark accuracy performance:

- UC Irvine - Knowledge Discovery in Databases [(KDD) Dataset Archive](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu)
- UToronto - Data for Evaluating Learning in Valid Experiments ([DELVE](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~delve))

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not looking for data to benchmark the performance. Instead what I'm looking for are benchmarks or standards to evaluate different features of data mining tools.

Answer (score 0):

This site: http://clopinet.com/challenges/ contains tons of datasets for machine learning techniques. The best part is that you can also compare your performance to that of others.